# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'ï»¿localhost' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following situation:

```
$DB_Environment = file('../DB/DB_Environment.txt');
$host = trim($DB_Environment[0]);
$dbname = trim($DB_Environment[1]);

$p1 = "mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname;
$user=trim($DB_Environment[2]);
$pass=trim($DB_Environment[3]);

try {
    $conection = new PDO($p1, $user, $pass);
    $conection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is an fragment of code that gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'ï»¿localhost' (2)
```

The code above finds the content on 1st to 4th lines in the `.txt` file that contains the data to configure the connection with the database.

It apparently works on my localhost, but when I run it on the server, the error appears. Then I changed the code to this:

```
try {
    $conection = new PDO("mysql:host=infojr.com.br;dbname=pluginfo", "myuser", "mypass");
    $conection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I changed the search on the `.txt` file by your content, and it works, but I want it to work like the first example, which only works on my localhost (PC).

Comment: Did you upload the text file in ASCII mode?

Comment: Looks like the File starts with a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark. Either fix this or open it in a different encoding.

Comment: I saw on sublime text, the encode is UTF-8 and there isn't the option to save in ASCII, what I need to do?

Comment: I found the problem, the server doesn't allow the execution of the file() method. How I can close this thread?